# I can't manage to add star rating to my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add some star rating widget on my test blog and nothing seems to work. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Here is my test blog url http://testvevvvv.blogspot.ro/2014/08/5.html and the code that i implemented http://jsfiddle.net/dyyehzwc/

```
<div class="rw-ui-container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, t, e, m){
        // Async Rating-Widget initialization.
    window.RW_Async_Init = function(){

        RW.init({
            huid: "187426",
            uid: "a36ac16a3021fa3c0fd85f05e757671b",
            source: "website",
            options: {
                "size": "medium",
                "style": "oxygen"
            } 
        });
        RW.render();
    };
        // Append Rating-Widget JavaScript library.
    var rw, s = d.getElementsByTagName(e)[0], id = "rw-js",
        l = d.location, ck = "Y" + t.getFullYear() + 
        "M" + t.getMonth() + "D" + t.getDate(), p = l.protocol,
        f = ((l.search.indexOf("DBG=") > -1) ? "" : ".min"),
        a = ("https:" == p ? "secure." + m + "js/" : "js." + m);
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;              
    rw = d.createElement(e);
    rw.id = id; rw.async = true; rw.type = "text/javascript";
    rw.src = p + "//" + a + "external" + f + ".js?ck=" + ck;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(rw, s);
    }(document, new Date(), "script", "rating-widget.com/"));</script>
```

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: Test works perfect for me ... ?

Comment: Working for me as well.

Comment: you can see the Stars rating? can someone give me a print screen? i'm using google chorme browser

Comment: I've tested on Firefox now and no stars are appearing ...?

Comment: It was working for me in both Chrome and Firefox, but now it's not, so whatever you just changed, since you posted this question, broke it. [Screenshot](http://s27.postimg.org/gkgo5lrgz/Screen_Shot_2014_08_22_at_12_23_02_PM.png)

Comment: Omg.. I have not change anything. What could be the problem? Something loads faster and hide that or what?